# How to restrict resizing a circle/rectangle to some radius/width/height in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabricjs and trying to restrict a rectangle so that it cannot be resized after it reaches a minimum radius in case of circle and minimum width/height in case of rectangle :

This is what I have done so far : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/8u1cqasa/28/) .

Code : 
`

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas2");
var circle, isDown, origX, origY;
circle = new fabric.Circle({
    left: 20,
    top: 30,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    radius: 30,
    angle: 0,
    fill: '',
    stroke:'red',
    strokeWidth:3,
});
canvas.add(circle);
function checkscale(e) {
        var obj = e.target;
        obj.setCoords();
        var b = obj.getBoundingRect();
        if(obj.toJSON().objects[0].radius == undefined) {
            //rectangle case
            if(obj.width < 27) {
                obj.width = 27;
            }
            if(obj.height < 27) {
                obj.height = 27;
            }
            return;
        } else {
            //circle case
            if(obj.width < 48) {
                obj.width = 48;
            }
            if(obj.height < 48) {
                obj.height = 48;
            }
            return;
        }
        if (!(b.left >= minX && maxX >= b.left + b.width && maxY >= b.top + b.height && b.top >= minY)) {
            obj.left = obj.lastLeft;
            obj.top = obj.lastTop;
            obj.scaleX= obj.lastScaleX
            obj.scaleY= obj.lastScaleY
        } else {
            obj.lastLeft = obj.left;
            obj.lastTop = obj.top;
            obj.lastScaleX = obj.scaleX
            obj.lastScaleY = obj.scaleY      
        }
    }
    canvas.observe("object:scaling", checkscale);
```

`
Can anybody do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to mess up with radius, toJson and width and height.
You are scaling a fabricJs object, so scaleX and scaleY is all you need.

Consider upgrading to fabricJs 1.6

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas2");
var circle, isDown, origX, origY;
circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 20,
        top: 30,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        radius: 30,
        angle: 0,
        fill: '',
        stroke:'red',
        strokeWidth:3,
        lockScalingFlip: true
    });
    canvas.add(circle);

function checkscale(e) {
  var obj = e.target;
  //var dim = obj._getTransformedDimensions();
  if (obj.getWidth() < 50) {
    obj.scaleX = obj.lastScaleX;
  } else {
    obj.lastScaleX = obj.scaleX;
  }
  if (obj.getHeight() < 50) {
    obj.scaleY = obj.lastScaleY;
  } else {
    obj.lastScaleY = obj.scaleY;
  }
}
canvas.observe("object:scaling", checkscale);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js" ></script>
<canvas id="canvas2" width=500 height=500 style="height:500px;width:500px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please note that in fabric 3.x scaling affects stroke as well! You could use `strokeUniform` property but it won't work in node.